# React renderizando componente na hora errada

Tags: javascript, react, render

Tenho uma página com 3 componentes em cascata (*um abre dentro do outro*), divididos por classes, só que ele tá renderizando antes de clicarmos em adicionar. O que pode ser?

Função que renderiza os itens quando já estão cadastrados:

```
showRows() {
   let lotes = [];
   if (this.state.loteRows.length > 0) {
     this.state.loteRows.map((r, key) => {
       console.log("console log em lotes", lotes);
       lotes.push(r);
     });
   }
   return lotes;
}
```

botão que adiciona os lotes com os itens:

```
<div id="lotes" className="col-md-12">
{/* <form>
  <div id="autocomplete">
  <input className="form-control" 
    id="sigmdados" 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Buscar" 
    value={value}
    onChange={this.handleChange} 
    required />
  </div>
</form> */}
<button className="btn btn-success pull-right" 
    onClick={() => { 
        this.state.verifyRows = true, 
        this.insertItem(this.state.loteRows.length, {}) 
    }} 
    type="button">
  Adicionar Registro de Preço
</button>
</div>
```

A div do botão está dentro de outra div e essa outra div contém a chamada `this.showRows`

```
</fieldset>
    {this.showRows()}
</div>
```

Comment: Na arrow function do onClick substitua a vígula por ponto e vírgula, assim haverá a quebra da linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua pergunta, vc só quer que não apareça nada enquanto a lista está vazia certo?

Nesse seu caso eu acredito que o que esteja faltando mesmo é você adicionar um if para validar isso, mas eu precisaria de mais informações pra te dar uma resposta melhor, pq daria pra resolver de infinitas formas, mas uma delas que seria mais simples e não teria que alterar nenhuma lógica seria essa:

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  {this.state.loteRows.length && this.showRows()}
</div>
```

Mas se você puder mandar um codepen, jsfiddle ou qualquer coisa do tipo mostrando melhor qual é o problema, acredito que eu possa te ajudar melhor!

tmj!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Valeu, Rafa! Era isso mesmo, esqueci de responder kkkkkkk